# Is the Sokhotski-Plemelj limit representation of the Dirac delta function unique in a sense?

Tags: complex-analysis, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

Suppose I know that a function is analytic in the upper half plane and that for real $x$ we have $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \operatorname{Im} f(x+ i \epsilon) = \delta(x)$. Can I conclude that $f(z) = \frac{-1}{\pi z}$? Is the Sokhotski-Plemelj formula unique in this sense?

(Context: I am reading a physics text on scattering theory and they appear to me to be using uniqueness in this sense.)

Comment: But [$\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to 0^+}(x+i\epsilon)^{-1}=-i\pi\delta(x)+\mathcal{P}\frac1x$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sokhotski%E2%80%93Plemelj_theorem#Version_for_the_real_line) is not quite what you state.

Comment: @metamorphy. How do you mean?